# Load certain parts of website into array in Android application

Tags: android, web, webview

So I want to load certain elements of a website into an array in an application.

For example this page:
http://www.danskespil.dk/spil/oddset/den_lange/resultater_den_lange.html

I would like to load the matches into one array, the odds into another array, and the results in a third array.

Answer (score 0):

Download the page using `HttpUrlConnection` or HttpClient. Use a Java HTML parser to parse the content. Use the parsed results to populate your arrays.